# How to use dynamic query string (index.php?page=student) in routerProvider while config

Tags: php, angularjs, ngroute

I face a problem in config part of routeprovider. In when section of routeprovider I want to register a url like index.php?page=student but it not working in case. here is the example

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
}).hashPrefix('!');
$routeProvider
.when('/index.php?comment=hello',{
    redirectTo:'/index.php'
});
```

Comment: Do you know about `routeParams`?

Comment: index.php?page=student is accept or not in routeProvider when?

Comment: How to work with routeParams?

Comment: Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewjmead/jDKP5/

Comment: If i simple use index.php in when then the define controller is called.

Comment: yes and in that controller you can use `$routeParams` and can get the value from it as shown in the above example

Comment: The problem is basically in when section. When section is not accepted this kind of url (/index.php?page=student).

Comment: No it doesn't, you have to give it like `/:YourParamName` like in this example: https://codepen.io/aronrodrigues/pen/raMpWK

Comment: Its not working.

Comment: any error? also can you post your html code?

Comment: i am not working in directory url. but am working in query string url

Comment: no error. it goes to otherwise function

Comment: i want to use angularjs with wordpress

Comment: ok so tell me what you have written using the example I have given you, it  is very simple and as per your need.

Comment: Its working in this case: if i define only index.php in when and in controller i get routeParams, it return only parameters after ?

Comment: app.controller('course',function($location,$routeParams){
 alert($routeParams.page); // page name in return
 alert($location.search().target);
 alert("Course Controller");
});

Comment: To get your parameter in controller you have to use `$routeParams.YourParamName` as in your case it will be `$routeParams.comment` and you can store its value in a variable and then use it

Comment: Yeah i saw. but i have 25 pages e.g page=student , page=course. I apply if statement 25 times or use case in main controller than redirect to other controller from main controller?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EvEGwY

Comment: for example:
In main controller
if($routeParams.page == 'student')
call student controller
if($routeParams.page == 'course')
call course controller

Comment: I guess then you have to use `switch-case`

Comment: Its good approach for calling controller?

Comment: I called 25+ controller from switch case or if statment.

Comment: No, its  not. Can you tell me the flow here? How the user will come to the application and go to another view?

Comment: First index.php call
then user move from tabs like student , course , enrollment etc
but every tab have href="admin.php?page=student" , href="admin.php?page=course" like this
In config
.when('/admin.php',{
controller:'main'
});

--Controller--
if($routeParams.page == 'student')
call student controller
else other

Comment: and what is there on index.php?

Comment: But i want to control all routing from config side:
Like: .when('/admin.php?page=student',{
   controller:student
})
.when('/admin.php?page=course',{
 controller:course
});
I want this type

Comment: This is not the way to do this, if you see the example https://codepen.io/aronrodrigues/pen/raMpWK you will see that it has two links just like your "Student" and "Course" so when you click on them, you have to write different code for them in config and as you already have different controller for them, you can use them and if you want to use same html code for all of them then you can use same html file in the `templateURL` part and give different controllers.

Comment: @AayushiJain thanks alot for helping and giving me your precious time :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions. If you have been asked for additional information, please [edit] it into your question. If you have solved your problem, please write it as an answer.

Comment: Ok :) but tell me where we discuss the problem in detail?